# Best way to add a "prompt" message to std::cout

Tags: c++

I'm searching the best way to add a custom, initial message to all the messages that `std::cout` (or `std::cerr`) prints to console/file output.

For example, if I setup that this custom prompt message will be the string "[Log]", then a classic

```
std::cerr << "This is a log message" << std::endl;
```

will be printed in this way:

```
> [Log] This is a log message
```

Clearly I can obtain this behavior using

```
std::string PROMPT_MSG = "[Log]";
std::cerr << PROMPT_MSG << "This is a log message" << std::endl;
```

but I'd like a less invasive way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simple answer is: You can't. You can however use a proper logging framework and use that instead, for example [Boost log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write your own class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyLogger
{
    std::ostream & out;
    std::string const msg;
public:
    MyLogger(std::ostream & o, std::string s)
    : out(o)
    , msg(std::move(s))
    { }

    template <typename T>
    std::ostream & operator<<(T const & x)
    {
        return out << msg << x;
    }
};

MyLogger MyErr(std::cerr, "[LOG] ");
```

Usage:

```
MyErr << "Hello" << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is interesting. But I need also the function `cout.rdbuf()`, does exist a similar way to redirect the output on a file with a custom class like this one?

Comment: @ital: Please make a new question that describes the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 5):

As Joachim Pileborg suggested you can use a logging framework. YOu can use an existing one or start with your own that will contain just one class:

```
class MyLogger{}
template <typename T>
MyLogger& operator << (MyLogger& logger, const T& logStuff)
{
   std::cerr << PROMPT_MSG << logStuff << std::endl;
   return logger;
}
```

then define a global variable of class MyLogger:

```
MyLogger mylogger;
```

then when you want to write a log record, write:

```
mylogger << "This is a log message";
```

overloaded operator << of class MyLogger will do what you want;

Comment: @KerrekSB If you mean that it will add newline after each "a", "b" and "c" then you can remove '<<std::endl' from operator and write it yourself each time you use it. If you mean something else then please clarify

Comment: A few months ago I answered a similar qestion. I help the OP with implementing a custom logger. I used `std::endl` manipulator as sentinel to print the log prompt. Here is the code: https://github.com/Manu343726/Cpp11CustomLogClass

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in a recent project. I solved it with this little class:

```
class DebugOut
{
public:
static const int COLUMN_WIDTH = 15;
DebugOut(const std::wstring &type)
{
    std::wcout << type;
    for(int i=type.length();i<COLUMN_WIDTH;i++)
        std::wcout << " ";
    std::wcout << ": ";
}

~DebugOut()
{
    std::wcout << std::endl;
}
template <typename T>
friend DebugOut& operator<<(DebugOut& out,T i)
{
    std::wcout << i;
    return out;
}
};
```

Sample usage: DebugOut(L"Log") << "Something";

Comment: As expected? "TEST  : abc"

Comment: Hm, could you make a compiling example and post it somewhere?

Comment: That explains a lot. This isn't actually valid C++ :-)

Comment: References, temporaries, rvalues, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just define a function `log` and a function `error`, and then just call them when you want to print a log or error method. That way you don't have to add the PROMPT_MSG every time.